# How do I keep an Int variable positive or 0 in Java

Tags: java

I have created a while loop in which a variable's value decreases each time. How do I program the variable such that it's value never goes negative?
for example if it's currently equal to 3 
and the input is 5 I want to program it so that 3-5 gives me zero not -2 .

Comment: Make a test for that variable being positive part of the condition of the while-loop. i.e. `while ((previous condition) && (variable > 0)) { ... variable decremented here ... }`

Comment: You will need to use something like `if(a) < 0; a=0;`

Comment: You can use: `Math.max(0, value);`

Comment: The easiest way would be creating a class `PositiveInt` that will provide methods like `increase(int)` and `decrease(int)` and it could handle your restriction. That way you don't have to clutter your algorithm with these "greater than 0" checks.

Comment: Since you're using a loop, I have to ask this **very important question**:  when does your loop stop?  So long as your loop actually ends, then keeping the variable positive is trivial, but I don't want this to be a case of you wanting an infinite loop for one reason or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// myVar is your variable and inputVar is the input variable
myVar= (myVar > inputVar) ? myVar-inputVar : 0;
```

The condition `(myVar > inputVar)`is tested. If it is `true` the first value, `myVar-inputVar`, is returned. If it is `false`, the second value, `0`, is returned

Answer (score 0):

you can check the value whether it is negative or positive

```
int result = var1 - var2 ;
if(result<0){
// print zero
}
else{
    // print result
}
```